# How can I use the hotspot functionality?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I'm running 20.04.1 LTS on an iMac using ethernet (internet works fine, I have tried to connect using wifi and it's just fine.)

1. I tried to use the regular method in settings (turn on Hotspot, setup name/password) but my other devices return either "Not connected to internet" or "Enter username and password".
2. Network connections: Deleted the network and created a new one. The result was the same.
3. Connect to a hidden network: didn't do it either.
4. I tried {sudo service network-manager restart}, I don't quite understand what this is but somebody suggested this in a forum.
   And that's my begginers story so far, I appreciate if anybody can shade some light into this, where should I research or what are possible solutions. Thank you.